# Merge fixed length multiple lists

Tags: python

How to merge fixed length multiple lists together to get a single list with the most updated value in a particular place. In example below, the result would be `[1,33,222,3333,11111]`.

```
l1 = [1,    "", 111,    "", 11111]
l2 = ["",   22, 222,    2222,   ""]
l3 = ["",   33, "", 3333,   ""]
l4 = ....
l5 = ...
....
```

Is there any inbuilt function to do this. I can do it using two loops but there must be some other smart ways to do the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip(l1, l2, l3)` and then `or` operator on tuples:

```
[tup[2] or tup[1] or tup[0] for tup in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
```

`or` operator returns the first true value. And since you want the last true value, so you need to apply `or` operator on tuple elements in reverse.

Or you can `zip` the lists in reverse, and use `or` operator in order:

```
[tup[0] or tup[1] or tup[2] for tup in zip(l3, l2, l1)]
```

---

**Update:**

Instead of variable number of list, I would suggest you to have a `list of list` instead. In that case you can get the result like this:

```
li = [[1,    "", 111,    "", 11111], 
      ["",   22, 222,    2222,   ""], 
      ["",   33, "", 3333,   ""], ..... so on
     ]

print [reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, tup) for tup in zip(*li[::-1])]
```

Comment: thanks but I have variable number of lists that I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is using `map` and a function to get the first non-blank item in a series of arguments:

```
def first_nonblank(*args):
    for item in args:
        if item is not '':
            return item

print map(first_nonblank, l3, l2, l1)
```

or

```
print map(first_nonblank, *li[::-1])
```

if `li` is a list of lists as in @Rohit Jain's answer.